# jquery compare two fields values

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

hi i have a sign up form , it has six input fields

## html code

```
<div id="signup">
    <form  id="suform" method="POST" action="signup/newUser">
        <p>
            <label>Frist Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="fName"/>
            <span class="errorMessage"></span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="lName"/>
            <span class="errorMessage"></span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="Email"/>
            <span class="errorMessage"></span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Mobile Number</label>
            <input type="text" name="MNumber"/>
            <span class="errorMessage"></span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="Password"/>
            <span class="errorMessage"></span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Re Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="RePassword"/>
            <span class="errorMessage"></span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" class="button" value="sign up"/>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

when the user clicked sign up button , first i ensure that no input fields is empty , if i found any input fields in empty then i print an error message left to that input field ,

## jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#suform').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var errorCount = 0;
        $('span.errorMessage').text(''); // reset all error mesaage
        $('input').each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            if($this.val() === ''){
                var error = 'Please fill ' + $this.prev('label').text(); // take the input field from label
                $this.next('span').text(error);
                errorCount = errorCount + 1;   
            }
        });
        if(errorCount === 0){
            $(this)[0].submit(); // submit form if no error
        }
    });
});
```

i want the user to input his password twice to ensure that he saves it

my question is how to check the two passwords input fields if they are equal or not , and if not i want to print a message error to the left of that two input fields

[code](http://jsfiddle.net/Wiliam_Kinaan/8wV58/4/)

Comment: why dont you use jquery validate plugin

Comment: today more than 10 people advice me to use it , but really i don't have time to learn jquery ,i know a very very little bit in jquery :(

Comment: Hate when it happens like that, first answer it works and I didn't get even 1 up vote!

Comment: sorry @infinity but where is ur answer ?

Comment: Check my solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10566234/464552

It contains check for empty password pass1 != '' so in case both passwords are empty it will throw an error

Comment: it works good man , really thank you , i hope i could accept more than answer :( :(

Comment: @infinity would u help me in checking the mobile number input filed , it it is not an number , always there should be an error , and thank you

Comment: You can check for a number like that:
function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
var pass1 = $('input[name=Password]').val();
var pass2 = $('input[name=RePassword]').val();
if(pass1 != '' && pass1 != pass2) {
    //show error
    var error = 'Password confirmation doesn\'t match.';
    $('input[name=Password]').next('span').text(error);
    $('input[name=RePassword]').next('span').text(error);
    errorCount = errorCount + 1;   
}
```

The "for" property in the label is used as follows:

```
<label for="myPasswordField">
    <input type="password" id="myPasswordField" name="Password" />
</label>
```

So when you click on the label this will set the focus on the related element with that ID attribute.

To check if the phone field is a number you need that:

```
var mobile = $('input[name=MNumber]').val();
if(isNaN(parseFloat(mobile )) && !isFinite(mobile )) {
    var error = 'Mobile number incorect.';
    $('input[name=MNumber]').next('span').text(error);
    errorCount = errorCount + 1; 
}
```

Comment: I would also recommend that William assign an `id` for each of his form inputs, as then his label can have a `for` property pointing to each.

Comment: but how to print the error message at the left of the two password input fields ?

Comment: what is for property in the label ?

Comment: ok thank you really thank you , i got the same exactly answer before 1 mins :) , i really thank you

Comment: @infinity please would u update ur answer to check it the mobile input fields is a number ,if not also an error , reallly thank you man

Comment: This will validate a number of the format: 07888999555 but if it has spaces it will fail

Comment: @infinity  IT woooooooooooooorks , really thank you i love you

Comment: @infinity can i ask you another question ? or u tired from me ? :)

Comment: go on @WilliamKinaan what's the question?

Answer (score 3):

Checking the fields and showing an error *without* jQuery:

```
if (document.forms[0].Password.value != document.forms[0].RePassword.value) {
    document.forms[0].Password.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("errorMessage")[0].innerHTML="Passwords aren't the same!";
    document.forms[0].RePassword.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("errorMessage")[0].innerHTML="Passwords aren't the same!";
}
```

If there is more than one form on the page (even just a search form) you'll need to adjust `document.forms[0]` accordingly.

To use this code in your form, add `onsubmit="return checkForm();"` to the form tag, like:

```
<form  id="suform" method="POST" action="signup/newUser" onsubmit="return checkForm();">
```

Then, in your script tag, create the function checkCode which will return false (in other words stop form submission) if there's a problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function checkCode() {
        if (document.forms[0].Password.value != document.forms[0].RePassword.value) {
            document.forms[0].Password.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("errorMessage")[0].innerHTML="Passwords aren't the same!";
            document.forms[0].RePassword.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("errorMessage")[0].innerHTML="Passwords aren't the same!";
            return false;
        }
    }
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: i got u, but have i call a js function and put ur code in it ?

Comment: On the form, add onsubmit="return checkForm();". In your <script> tag, add the function checkForm() with that code, and on a new line before the closing curly bracket } put the code return false;

Comment: Cool, I updated the post with all the implementation details and code.

Answer (score 2):

Well this might work i suppose.,

```
 var password= $('input[name="Password"]').val();
 var repass= $('input[name="RePassword"]').val();

 if(password!=repass){
  var error = 'Password not matching';
       $('input[name="RePassword"]').next('span').text(error);
       $('input[name="Password"]').next('span').text(error);
         errorCount = errorCount + 1;  
  }else if(password=="" || repass==""){
            if(password==""){
        var error = 'Please enter a password.';
       $('input[name="Password"]').next('span').text(error)
         errorCount = errorCount + 1;  
    }else{
           var error = 'Please enter a repassword.';
       $('input[name="RePassword"]').next('span').text(error)
         errorCount = errorCount + 1;  
  }
   }
   }else{
     continue;
    }
```

Comment: you are the one man , yes it works :) :) thank you i will accept ur answer , really thank you

Comment: This is not reliable solution, there is a problem with the check.

Comment: thanks mate, happy to help. =) @infinity, Can you please suggest whats wrong cuz i'm a newbie and still learning. It would be rely helpful.

Comment: You need to check for empty password value like: password != ''

Answer (score 1):

```
    <p>
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="Password"/>
        <span class="errorMessage"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Re Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="RePassword"/>
        <span class="errorMessage"></span>
    </p>


if ( $("input[type=password][name='Password']").val() == $("input[type=text][name='RePassword']").val(){
    //Do this
}
```

Comment: yes man , you are right , but how to print the error message at the left of each passwords input fields ? as my demo

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/K5CMC/

```
var $this = $(this);

            if($this.val() === ''){
                var error = 'Please fill ' + $this.prev('label').text(); // take the input field from label
                $this.next('span').text(error);
                errorCount = errorCount + 1;   
            }else if($this.attr('id') === 'Password'){
                //compare the two fields
                if($('#Password').val() !== $('#RePassword')){
                    //they don't match, do stuff

                }
            }
```

Comment: Checked the jsFiddle? It works over there... Updated it with a alert; the alert shows when the're not equal. http://jsfiddle.net/K5CMC/2/

Comment: You're welcome. Look closely to all the solutions that have been given. My advise: combine the best of all

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this [Demo on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H9f2f/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#suform').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var errorCount = 0;
        $('span.errorMessage').text(''); // reset all error mesaage
        $('input').each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            if($this.val() === ''){
                var error = 'Please fill ' + $this.prev('label').text(); // take the input field from label
                $this.next('span').text(error);
                errorCount = errorCount + 1;   
            }
            else
            if($(this).attr('name') == "RePassword")
                if($('input[name=Password]').val() != $(this).val())
                    alert("must have same password");
        });
        if(errorCount === 0){
            $(this)[0].submit(); // submit form if no error
        }
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#suform').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var errorCount = 0;
        $('span.errorMessage').text(''); // reset all error mesaage
        $('input').each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            if($this.val() === ''){
                var error = 'Please fill ' + $this.prev('label').text(); // take the input field from label
                $this.next('span').text(error);
                errorCount = errorCount + 1;   
            }
        });
        if($('input[name="Password"]').val() != $('input[name="RePassword"]').val())
        {
            var error = 'Password not match'; // take the input field from label
            $('input[name="RePassword"]').next('span').text(error);
            errorCount = errorCount + 1;   
        }
        if(errorCount === 0){
            $(this)[0].submit(); // submit form if no error
        }
    });
});
```