# Compare two text inputs with comma seperated values return true if one input contains only values that are inside the other input

Tags: javascript, jquery

When you have two inputs that both have comma separated values. How can I compare these so that I can get an `if match` then do this `else` do that.

```html
<input type='text' class='focusfield' value=''>

<input type='text' class='fixed' value='4002,4003,4004,4005,4006,4007'>


// Example 1 for generated input (should return FALSE)
<input type='text' class='generated' value='3500,3700,4002,4006,4007,4005,4004,4003'>

// Example 2 for generated input (should return FALSE)
<input type='text' class='generated' value='3500'>

// Example 3 for generated input (should return TRUE)
<input type='text' class='generated' value='4002,4006,4007,4005,4004,4003'>

// Example 4 for generated input (should return TRUE)
<input type='text' class='generated' value='4002'>
```

Notice that the `generated` input does not have the same order as the `fixed` field.

When **all the numbers** into input `generated` are also present into input `fixed` then it should return true otherwise it should return false. This code has to run when leaving the `focusfield`.

Inside a document ready function I have the following (which is the only part that works from everything I tried see the below links):

```js
$('.focusfield').focusout(function(){

});
```

I have tried working the below answers into my code but none of them provided the result and usually I can get it close to what I want with the existing SO questions but this time I don't. So I don't have a partial working code to start out from.

[how to compare value with comma separated value in javascript or jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398651/how-to-compare-value-with-comma-separated-value-in-javascript-or-jquery/30398800)

[how to compare two currency in jquery with comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52345714/how-to-compare-two-currency-in-jquery-with-comma)

[jquery compare two fields values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566202/jquery-compare-two-fields-values)

[compare two input values using Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37988241/compare-two-input-values-using-jquery)

[comparing two strings with comma separated values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884283/comparing-two-strings-with-comma-separated-values) (is for c+ but I could get an idea from it but sadly I did not.)

[multiple comma seperate value compare using JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40156597/multiple-comma-seperate-value-compare-using-js)

I have more links in my history but I don't think it adds to the question I just wanted to post these links so that everyone knows I am not just here asking for free code ;-0.

Thanks to everyone who is helping and took the time to read all this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let works with minimal code:

```
const goal = '4002,4003,4004,4005,4006,4007';
const test ='3500,3700,4002,4006,4007,4005,4004,4003';
```

You want a method that returns true if every test number is contained inside goal.

```
function inside(a, b) {
  //array of numbers
  const aV = a.split(',').map( e => +e);
  const bV = b.split(',').map( e => +e);

  //every b must be in a
  return bV.every( v => aV.indexOf(v) !== -1 );
}
```

```js
const goal = '1,2,3';
const test ='1,2';

function inside(b, a) {
  //array of numbers
  const aV = a.split(',').map( e => +e);
  const bV = b.split(',').map( e => +e);

  //every b must be in a
  return bV.every( v => aV.indexOf(v) !== -1 );
}

console.log('Is', test);
console.log('inside', goal);
console.log('=>', inside(test, goal) );
```

**Edition**

Here is a step by step solution
You need a function that take two strings and returns a boolean.

```
function inside(a,b) {
    return true;
}
```

Working with 'array as string coma separated' is painful... let's convert string to array, split with ','

```
function inside(b, a) {
  //array of numbers
  const aV = a.split(',');
  const bV = b.split(',');
  return true
}
```

Then I changed from array of string to array of number, with `.map( e => +e)` and this is totally useless haha... sorry... so let's forget that

Ok so we want to be sure that every value in Bv is in aV.
So for a given value in Bv like x, we want to test that x is in aV. Let's check the index of x in aV : `aV.indexOf(x)`
If it is `-1`, it means `not present`...

Great let take for every bV !!!

```
function inside(b, a) {
  //array of numbers
  const aV = a.split(',');
  const bV = b.split(',');

  for( let i = 0; i < bV.length; i++) {
    const x = bV[i];
    const index = aV.indexOf(x);

    if ( index === -1 ) {
        //Not present, we stop here
        return false;
    }
  }

  //So we check for every Bv and none were absent, let's return true
  return true;
}
```

Ok it works but... I don't like using `for` with Array, let's do it with `forEach`

```
function inside(b, a) {
  //array of numbers
  const aV = a.split(',');
  const bV = b.split(',');

  //Let's define everything is ok
  let result = true;

  bV.forEach( x => {
    if ( aV.indexOf(x) === -1 )
        result = false;
  })

  return result;
}
```

Great but that's exacty the point of the `every` method !

```
function inside(b, a) {
  //array of numbers
  const aV = a.split(',');
  const bV = b.split(',');

  return bV.every( x => {
    if ( aV.indexOf(x) === -1 )
        result = false;
    return true;
  })
}
```

Let's short that

```
function inside(b, a) {
  //array of numbers
  const aV = a.split(',').map( e => +e);
  const bV = b.split(',').map( e => +e);

  //every b must be in a
  return bV.every( v => aV.indexOf(v) !== -1 );
}
```

See [Array.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), [String.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [Array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: I just tested this in a fiddle and it works perfectly. Is it possible for you to point me to some documents where I can learn this code step by step or point me out to some search arguments to use. Or if you are willing to add more comments than that would be even better. Nonetheless, I want to thank you because with your code you are ending a couple of frustrating hours of me. So thank you very much!

Comment: I added a more detailled solution

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I meant I am going to read this a dozen times. This is amazing thank you so much! This makes it so much easier for me to understand what you did. I have never had such a detailed answer. THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a couple of javascript built in function.

You first split the values, store them in an array and sort the values.
The you can compare the elements of this array are equal to the source array.

I've made a jsfiddle to explain it.
https://jsfiddle.net/3cLa5614/

```
function checkValues(input) {
    const sources = document.getElementById('source').value.split(',').sort();
    const values = input.value.split(',').sort();

    let comparator = sources.splice(0,values.length);
    return JSON.stringify(comparator)==JSON.stringify(values)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I did however already choose the other answer, and I am sticking with that choice but I do appreciate your answer and upvoted it, and I am sure that you are going to receive more up votes in the years to come.